# Question about Issacs Group theory Exercise 14.3 part c Hint

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

[image]

I am able to solve this question in full, but I have a question about the hint. I need help justifying why the Hint implies that $P$ is prime. Thanks.

Here is what I have so far.

Let $f,g\in R\setminus P$ where $fg\in P$. We need to reach a contradiction. I am trying to apply the hint with $A=\langle P\cup \{f\}\rangle$ and $B=\langle P\cup \{g\}\rangle$. I'm having trouble showing that $AB\subseteq P$.

The problem is, We have something like $rfsgt\in AB$ with $r,s,t\in R$, which may not be in $\langle fg \rangle$. Should I have chosen $A,B$ differently?

Note that $R$ is assumed to have unity but may not be commutative.

Comment: If $P$ is not prime, then there are $a,b\not\in P$ such that $ab\in P$. Then $A=P+(a)>P$ and $B=P+(b)>P$  but $AB\subseteq P$.

Comment: Exactly my question. why do we have $AB\subseteq P$?

Comment: $(p+ca)(p'+db)= ...$

Comment: $(p+ca)(p′+db)=...$ is not quite the correct way to think about it. $R$ is not necessarily commutative, so you need to multiply by $a,b$ on *both left and right sides*. Like $cac'$ and $dbd'$.

Comment: OK, multiply on both sides.

Comment: please help me! Is it true that $(ab)=(a)(b)$? The noncommutativity of $R$ is what's making it difficult.

Comment: It is not true in the noncommutative case. In fact the set theoretic product of ideals is not necessarily an ideal.

Comment: Note also that the def of a prime ideal in noncomm. case is different.